# Покрыть блок полностью изображением

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```
<div id="saveName" class="saveName" style="display: none;">
    <div class="saveName__wrapper">
        <h1 class="saveName__h1" id="saveNameH1">Чтобы сохранить результаты, введите ваше  имя:</h1>
    </div>
    <input id="saveNameInput" type="text" class="saveName__input" required maxlength="10">
    <br> 
    <p class="saveName__error-message" id="saveNameErrorMessage"></p>
    <button type="submit" class="saveName__saveButton" id="saveNameSaveButton"> Сохранить </button>
    <div class="saveName__timeToSave">
        <h1 class="saveName__timerPrinter"><span id="saveNameTimeWord"> Ваше время </span> - <span id="saveNameTimerPrinterMin">00</span>:<span id="saveNameTimerPrinterSec">00</span>.<span id="saveNameTimerPrinterMS">00</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>



CSS
.saveName{
  background-color: black; 
  background-image: url('public/example.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%; 
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
```

}

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы этот деревянный блок полностью покрывал весь черный блок и блока не было видно. "background-size: cover;" не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возьмите свою картинку и вырежете в Paint лишние

Comment: мне дизайнер такую дал

Comment: для того, чтобы обрезать картинку, не нужно быть дизайнером - есть множество бесплатных онлайн сервисов, например: https://www.iloveimg.com/ru/crop-image

Comment: а как нужно обрезать?

Comment: @Максим Зачем вам блок saveName черного цвета?